# SQL group by, sum, total query

Tags: t-sql

Can someone help with the query? 
I have a table here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aas](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [Status] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [price] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('a', 23)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('a', 23)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('a', 23)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('b', 4)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('b', 4)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('b', 4)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('b', 4)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('c', 8)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('c', 8)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('c', 8)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('c', 8)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('c', 8)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
insert into [dbo].[aas] ([Status], [price])
values ('y', 2)
```

I am expecting an output like this:

```
TotalA TotalPriceA TotalB TotalPriceB TotalC TotalPriceC TotalY TotalPriceY
3 69 4 16 5 40 12 24
```

But this query returns redundant data:

```
select 
COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [TotalA],
case when [status] = 'a' then
    sum(price)
    else 0
END as [TotalpriceA],

COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [TotalB],
case when [status] = 'b' then
    sum(price)
    else 0
END as [TotalpriceB],

COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [TotalC],
case when [status] = 'c' then
    sum(price)
    else 0
END as [TotalpriceC],

COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] = 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [TotalY],
case when [status] = 'y' then
    sum(price)
    else 0
END as [TotalpriceY]
from [dbo].[aas]
group by [status]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Group By is going to return one row per 'Status', that's why you are getting 4 rows.

This is the query you want. Though you may want to pivot the data.

```
SELECT  [status], count(*) as 'Total', sum(price) as 'TotalPrice'
from aas
group by [status]
```